# Hover function repeating whenever you move mouse inside selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an animation that fires on hover inside certain divs. When the mouse is in the div, moving it to a different location in the div causes the hover effect to trigger again. I've tried using mouseenter/mouseleave and that does the same thing.

How can I make the function only trigger on mouseenter and mouseleave and not whenever it moves inside the selector?

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4gub9wLw/1/)

```
$('#nav, #footer, #leftNav, #rightNav').hover(function() {
  $('#navFill').animate({
    left: 0
  }, 300);
  $('#footerFill').animate({
    left: 0
  }, 300);
  $('#leftNavFill').animate({
    top: 0
  }, 300);
  $('#rightNavFill').animate({
    top: 0
  }, 300);
}, function() {
  $('#navFill').animate({
    left: '-100vw'
  }, 300);
  $('#footerFill').animate({
    left: '100vw'
  }, 300);
  $('#leftNavFill').animate({
    top: '100vh'
  }, 300);
  $('#rightNavFill').animate({
    top: '-100vh'
  }, 300);
});
```

Comment: The animation should get triggered/stop when you enter/leave which DIV?

Comment: there are four divs that are selected. The top, left, right and bottom bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code you are calling both the animation at the same hover event, or lets say you are trying to animate it at the same mouseenter and mouseleave event. Instead of it try something like this.

```js
    $('#nav, #footer, #leftNav, #rightNav').mouseenter(function() {
console.log("mouseenter");
  $('#navFill').animate({
    left: 0
  }, 300);
  $('#footerFill').animate({
    left: 0
  }, 300);
  $('#leftNavFill').animate({
    top: 0
  }, 300);
  $('#rightNavFill').animate({
    top: 0
  }, 300);
});


$('#navFill, #footerFill, #leftNavFill, #rightNavFill').mouseleave(function() {
console.log("mouseleave");
  $('#navFill').animate({
    left: '-100vw'
  }, 300);
  $('#footerFill').animate({
    left: '100vw'
  }, 300);
  $('#leftNavFill').animate({
    top: '100vh'
  }, 300);
  $('#rightNavFill').animate({
    top: '-100vh'
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
#nav {
  background-color: rgba(86, 55, 144, 0.95);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 7.5vh;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #000;
  position: fixed;
}

#navBars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5vw;
  transform: scaleY(.75);
  line-height: 7.5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

#navigation {
  margin-left: 10vw;
}

.navigation {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  left: -3vw;
  margin-left: 3vw;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 7.5vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

#leftNav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 2vw;
  background-color: rgba(86, 55, 144, 1);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 11;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px #000;
}

#rightNav {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 2vw;
  left: 98vw;
  background-color: rgba(86, 55, 144, 1);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 11;
  box-shadow: -2px 0px 3px #000;
}

#footer {
  background-color: rgba(86, 55, 144, 0.95);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5vh;
  top: 95vh;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 3px #000;
  position: fixed;
}

#navFill {
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, .95);
  width: 100vw;
  left: -100vw;
  height: 7.5vh;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
}

#footerFill {
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, .95);
  width: 100vw;
  left: 100vw;
  top: 95vh;
  height: 5vh;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
}

#leftNavFill {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 2vw;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1);
  top: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 11;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px #000;
}

#rightNavFill {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 2vw;
  left: 98vw;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1);
  top: -100vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 12;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x" id="navBars"></i>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li id="homeNav" class="navigation">Home</li>
    <li id="aboutNav" class="navigation">About</li>
    <li id="portNav" class="navigation">Portfolio</li>
    <li id="contactNav" class="navigation">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="leftNav"></div>
<div id="rightNav"></div>
<footer id="footer">

</footer>
<div id="leftNavFill"></div>
<div id="rightNavFill"></div>
<div id="navFill"></div>
<div id="footerFill"></div>
```

Here is the Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gub9wLw/11/)

And also as soon as the mouse enters the div you are animating navFill and others which are not the same divisions to which the mousenter event is binded. So the mouseleave event executes at the same time because of the animation which cause the div to animate and thus the mouseleave event executes.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I want it to do. When the mouse enters any of the four divs the white animation should occur and stay there until mouseout. Here is a site with similar animation http://www.curadmir.com/routes

Comment: i do understand what you want. I think you are not getting what actually is happening while execution. Have updated the code and fiddle also have a look at it. And if you want i can try to explain what actually was the issue

Comment: I was just posting my own answer that looks exactly the same, I'm not sure why it acts weird in the fiddle but it works in my files. Is there a more optimal way to execute this?

Comment: Actually what actually was happening was. When the animation happens the navFill div and others *Fill divs were coming over the other divs. An because of this the mouse was leaving the those divs and entering the *Fill divs thus triggering the corresponding leave and enter events. And in fiddle its not working properly for the #nav div because of its height and other CSS.

Comment: have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4gub9wLw/13/ Have changed a bit of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The animation might cause the whole nav to shrink, because of this, the navigation consider the mouse "just enter" into the nav.

Comment: doing that just causes a delay between animations, but moving the mouse inside the div still causes the animation to reoccur.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with your animated DIVs (i.e. `#navFill`, `#leftNavFill`, `#rightNavFill`, and `#footerFill`) being above your non-animated DIVs (i.e. `#nav`, `#leftNav`, `#rightNav`, and `#footer`). When an animated DIV gets animated, it repaints the non-animated DIV below it causing it to trigger the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` event. Maybe in simple terms, as soon as the grey bar covers the purple area and the mouse, you just *left* the purple area (which causes the `mouseleave` event). And vice-versa, when the grey bar uncovers the purple area.

So, the problem came down to how do I make the animated DIVs appear above the non-animated DIVs without them being *selectable*? You can attach the CSS property `pointer-events: none` to your animated DIVs.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v6dah8ur/)